# Windows cannot run .ksh script

Tags: windows, cygwin, ksh

I have a java code under eclipse that is calling a .ksh script. The OS is Windows7.
I am a complete noob in shell things and the code (both java and ksh) were not written by me (and I cannot change it).

Anyway, when it tries to launch the script, the common Windows popup appears to let me choose a proper application. Given that, I have installed cygwin, but in cygwin/bin/ there is no ksh.exe at all. Even more, I didn't find any on google.

Is there any other way to launch the ksh under Windows?

Thanks in advance

I finally found a log:

```
C:\Users\Andrea\Desktop\AppXXX\Scripts\Model\Launchksh[35]: mkdir: not found
C:\Users\Andrea\Desktop\AppXXX\Scripts\Model\Launch.ksh[37]: can't create /rep/log/Launch_model.log: No such file or directory
```

It doesn't find mkdir, is it not an issue related with cygwin?

Comment: https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-install-ksh-in-cygwin

Comment: I already tried, but no ksh.exe appears in bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the `mksh` (MirBSD Korn Shell) package. Re-run setup and select `mksh`.

Comment: I have also done it. Unfortunately with no results as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "no results"? Doing what I suggested will certainly install ksh.

Comment: Yes but the script doesn't run. I am sure it works 'cause it comes from another dept where they everyday use it under linux

Comment: I have added a log to better explain the issue

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the mistery. In the PATH variable there was no reference to the cygwin/bin folder. I manually add it and now it runs!
Thanks all